# Question about integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is this true? If it is, why? And if are there any condtions I want to know them, or is it just wrong?

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(x\right)\text{y}\left(z\right)\space\text{d}x\space\text{d}z=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(x\right)\text{y}\left(z\right)\space\text{d}z\space\text{d}x$$

Comment: You should check Fubini's theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Am I wrong or the equality you have written is trivial?
$$\int\int \left(f(x)y(z) dxdz\right)=\int \int\left(f(x)y(z) dzdx\right)$$ always. Fubini's theorem is a stronger result

Comment: Thinking further, if $f y$ is integrable over $\mathbb R^+\times \mathbb R^+$, you can switch integration order without using Fubini's theorem because $f$ is independent by  $z$ (or $y$ by $x$)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write the iterated integral $\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\,y(z)\,dx\right)\,dz $ as

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\,y(z)\,dx\right)\,dz&=\int_0^\infty y(z)\left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx\right)\,dz\\\\
&=\left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx\right) \left(\int_0^\infty y(z)\,dz\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.   I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Provided the double integral converges absolutely, yes, you may swap the order of the two integrals with domain the rectangle formed by first quadrant.

As mentioned above, this is thanks to Fubini's theorem.